# Convergence of Bessel integral function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, bessel-functions

I have no idea how to prove the convergence. I am told I have to use the comparison test. I have split the integral from $0$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $+\infty$. I know $\cosh(t)\geqslant 1$ and $e^{-x}>0$. But now I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: $e^z/2 \leq \cosh(z) \leq e^z$. Now replace both cosh terms by one of these bounds in such a way that the overall quantity becomes smaller. (In one term you want the upper bound, in the other term you want the lower bound.)

Comment: Which Bessel Integral representation?

Comment: This has been completed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$K_\alpha(x) \approx \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{2}e^t+\alpha t\right)\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty} z^{\alpha-1}e^{-xz/2}\,dz$$
and:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} z^{\alpha-1}e^{-xz/2}\,dz = \left(\frac{2}{x}\right)^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha).$$

Comment: Thanks but where did the 1/2 come from?

Comment: I know the gamma integral converges so am I done? So there was no need to split the integral?

Comment: @John: There are no singularities in the integration range hence there is no need to split the integral. You just have to justify that by replacing $\cosh$ with $\frac{1}{2}\exp$ we do not affect convergence, but that is quite trivial.